# mac osx 10.7 install script error: "~/Library/" not found

Tags: macos, bash, osx-lion

I use a bash script to install an app on Mac OS X "Lion". First I copy the app bundle into place, then attempt to install postgres into the app bundle. The data path for the postgres db needs to be in "~/Library/Application Support/myappfolder/data/".

Now the problem (appears to be) that the script stumbles because the OS says the path is not found. Backing up the path names I get to "~/Library/" and it still fails. The script is run with admin privileges.

To put this another way, from the terminal, this works:

```
   me: cd ~/Library
```

but this does not:

```
   me: mydir="~/Library/"
   me: cd $mydir
```

I know things have changed in 10.7, but I haven't found the answer at the dev center yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is Lion-specific.  When you use quote marks, you are causing the `~` character to be treated literally, instead of as an alias for `$HOME`.  So it's looking for an actual directory with a tilde in the name, which doesn't exist.

Try using `mydir="$HOME/Library"` instead to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks, this works and fits well in the installer script. As I noted in the other comment, this has nothing to do with osx.

Answer (score 1):

This actually doesn't work in 10.5, either, so I don't think it's a Lion specific problem. Something like this will always work, though:

```
eval "cd $mydir"
```

Comment: This works too, and you are right, the problem was between the chair and keyboard, not with osx.